# Center a table with a fixed position

Tags: css, html

Hey all, i'm trying to center a table in a fixed position in a page but i am failing badly. How do i do this!?!? here's what i've done...

http://pastebin.com/cjAqkyjg

Comment: you are closing a anchor tag that yo've never opened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the size of the element (for example 200 x 100 px), you can center it using percentages and a negative margin that is half the size:

```
.Centered {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8pt4p/15/.

You need some CSS to make it work properly (this is just for the demo, so you'll need to apply an `id` to your elements):

**CSS**:

```
div#navigation {
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 100%;
}

div#navigation table {
    border: 1px solid red;

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <img src="Images/navigation.png" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a "top" and "left" css property on the div along wit fixed.

Comment: i did this and nothing: <div style="margin:0 auto; position:fixed; top:0px: left:0px;">

Answer (score 0):

You ought to be able to do it like this:

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin:0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
}
```

Unfortunately some browsers (Opera, IE9 (IE8 does it right)) get it wrong.